# AngularJS: Use function call for attribute value which is not an angular attribute

Tags: html, angularjs

I have created a webpage with custom directives, in my main controller there is a function called isReadOnly(arg) which takes one argument and returns true or false. I am able to call this function for attributes like ng-show like this:

```
ng-show="isReadOnly('fieldName')"
```

And it works fine, the function is called.
But for other custom attributes other than ng-show the function is never called and I do not know why.

Comment: Which 'other custom attributes'?

Comment: In my custom directive there is a field in the scope called uxReadonly, looks like this: scope: {uxReadonly: '='}

Comment: And how do you use that `uxReadonly` property in your directive?

Comment: If uxReadonly is true then clicking the dropdown does not show any items